# Disconnect Chromecast when device leaves Wi-Fi network

Tags: wifi, chromecast, disconnect

I am developing an iOS application with Chromecast. I would like to disconnect the Chromecast (stop playing the content) when the device that sent the content leaves the Wi-Fi network. Is it possible to do this? How would you implement it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do this? This is against the Cast UX design, and frankly, provides a bad user experience. Also, consider a case where your connectivity to the wifi is dropped temporarily for whatever reason, do you really want to stop the playback? What if there is another sender connected at the same time, do you still want to stop it? Lets say your phone goes to sleep and loses connectivity, do you want to stop the playback?

As for the possibility of doing it, it obviously cannot be driven from the sender side since it has lost its connectivity. On the receiver side, you get a callback when senders get connected or disconnected, along with a "reason" so you need to implement your logic there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You're right in all your remarks, issue is that by app design, the content should be "tied" to the device as it is behind a paywall. If the content is not stopped when the device leaves, users could be distributing the content freely through Chromecasts. Would you have any suggestion for this?

Anyway, we will investigate about the way to do it on the receiver side.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you look at all the other paid content, such as Netflix, Hulu, etc., none of them take any drastic measure like what you mentioned and I am not sure why/how you are worried about "free distribution" of content; there is no "distribution" involved in this case; in worst case scenario, for a person without the subscription, he/she gets to see a portion of a movie when a paid/subscribed friend comes over and that is the same if the paid person sits through the movie or if he/she leaves half way.

Comment: I agree that VoD services would not be very affected by this. However in this case service consists of live channels, so there is no "end" and thus the harm could be bigger. It's a remote possibility (you would have to leave TV on permanently to not lose the channel), but one we have considered anyway. I was asking this question because I have seen other apps do it but I could not figure out how, since as you point, you cannot send messages to Chromecasts once the device is disconnected. Seems we will have to go the receiver route, if ever. Thank you again!

Comment: I suggest, if you have to do something along those lines,  to do the following: in the receiver, if you noticed that the device that started the receiver has been disconnected for more than, say, 3 hrs, then shutdown the receiver.